# Print step into a function

Tags: r

In a function like this:

```
words <- c("stock", "revenue", "continuous improvement")
phrases <- c("blah blah stock and revenue", "yada yada revenue yada", 
             "continuous improvement is an unrealistic goal", 
             "phrase with no match")

df<- data.frame(lapply(words, function(word) {as.numeric(grepl(word, phrases))}))
```

how is it possible to use print(i) where i is the number of rows of phrases dataframe in which the function executed?. Aiming to know how much time the process needs to end.

Answer (score 1):

try this, good luck

```
df<- data.frame(lapply(1:length(words), function(i) {print(i); as.numeric(grepl(words[i], phrases))}))
```